# Crashlytics not sending reports from the app [android]

Tags: crashlytics

My app is unable to send reports through CrashLytics.

The log shows `CrashlyticsCore: Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable.`

I have also tried doing this but with no result

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().build();
Fabric.with(context, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

Comment: Paul from Crashlytics here. Are you using Firebase? If so, I would try removing the Builder initialization and the Fabric.with lines and use the standard Firebase initialization method. If not, please contact us at support(dot)fabric(dot)io and we can debug it further there.

Comment: I face the same issue. You should add flag to start the Crashlytics SDK. The Google link is : [Firbase Crashlytics SDK Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-android)